# All inflated items are vanished when screen orientation changes

Tags: android

Please somebody help me..

In my activity i use a loop to inflate items using LayoutInflator Service. There are some TextViews also in my activity. The TextView values remain unchanged but all the inflated items are vanished when i change the screen Orientation..

I know that the activity is recreated again to redraw the UI to match the layouts and all so I tried saving instance to a bundle. But helpless. Can i save these Inflated Items to that bundle and restore it on restore.

One guy told me to hide the soft keyboard when you change the orientation. I set properties on the manifest and also hiding keyboard on the orientation change event listener.

The only way now i can protect my app is to turn off the auto orientation. But thats not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

In the manifest, put `android:configChanges = "orientation"` for this activity. This will prevent the activity from being destroyed and recreated when you rotate the screen.

Note that you have to be very careful when doing this. If any of your resources depend on the orientation configuration (like if you have a resource folder called values-land or drawable-port, etc.) then these resources must be reloaded after the configuration change. See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges).